# org-mode latex export: wrap text around a table

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode

I can make text wrap around images by adding

```
#+CAPTION: foo
#+ATTR_LATEX: :float wrap
[[./my_img.png]]
```

If I do the same to

```
#+CAPTION: bar
#+ATTR_LATEX: :float wrap
| a | b |
| c | d |
```

The table will stay centered in its own part of the document, the text being broken above and below it, not auto-flowing around it.

I also tried to do something like

```
#+CAPTION: baz
#+ATTR_LATEX: :environment wraptable :options {l}{5cm}
| a | b |
| c | d |
```

or using `:position` instead of `:options`, with no results.

Basically I want the table to export to

```
\begin{wraptable}{l}{5cm}
   \begin{tabular}
   ....
   \end{tabular}
\end{wraptable}
```

in the tex file. The arguments `{r|l}{width}` are mandatory, so simply `#+begin_wraptable` won't work either. Is there any way to do that from inside org-mode without manually fiddling with the final .tex?

Answer (score 2):

You have to explicitly add the LaTeX-code for *wraptable*, using the *:center* attribute with no value removes the automatic insertion of *\beginn{center}* in the .tex-file.

```
#+LaTeX: \begin{wraptable}{r|l}{width}
#+ATTR_LATEX: :center 

| A      | B     | C     |
|--------+-------+-------|
| a      | b     | c     |

#+LaTeX: \end{wraptable}
```